# How would one describe a person who is not convinced by strong evidence in support of a theory

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which best describes a person who cannot be convinced by strong evidence presented in support of a theory. He may or may not present counter-arguments, but he is adamant in his refusal to be convinced.

For example

> I have shown her all the evidence which convinces me that the theory is
>   correct, but she is still __________ and says that the arguments are flawed.

The word ‘unconvinced’ would fit the blank here, but my request is for a stronger word than ‘unconvinced’ because the person in question will not discuss the evidence I have presented, but will only argue the case from other standpoints.

Comment: idiot.  religious nutcase.

Comment: Seems like he's in denial.

Comment: *Intransigent*, *truculent*, more in a thesaurus.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a word like 'Intolerant': "Not tolerant of views, beliefs, or behavior that differ from one's own." It doesn't quite nail it directly on the head but it can be close given circumstances.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you mean a person who holds out for strong evidence or a person who denies strong evidence that goes against his beliefs.  The first kind of person is essential to the advancement of science; the second --- well, no need to spell it out, is there?  Please clarify.

Comment: Can you clarify this question for me? Is the person denying the truth of the theory or accepting it but only tentatively? Many of the answers seem to think you mean the former, but your question title suggests to me the latter as perhaps does the odd phrase with which you finish "rigid about saying okay".

Comment: The single-word request tag says "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: A theory is not something that is proven.

Comment: @Clare See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theory), scroll down to "Two distinct, yet different meanings of theory" and then further to Synonym Discussion of Theory.  Also note loose use of theory and law.  Newton's Law of Gravitation applies in a much more limited range of conditions than Einstein's Theory of General Relativity, but all of us rely on our GPS.

Comment: @ab2 my comment is perhaps of little import, but regarding yours  the OP does not state *which kind* of theory he or she is referring to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of clarity. We do not know whether the OP is referring to a person who thinks the earth is flat, or a person who maintains that General Relativity needs work to be made consistent with Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: I've always had a soft spot for the description "invincibly ignorant".

Comment: @ab2, I disagree that the question is off-topic.  I do think the question is a bit misleading because the other person certainly wouldn't see themselves as having being presented "all the facts."  -- unless they are lying to themselves.

Comment: @thomj1332 We could take this much further afield than the OP might like!  But he does need to clarify.  He may be trying to avoid controversy by not giving an example of what kind of theory he is talking about, but the word or phrase for a person who rejects Evolution is very different from the person who thinks String Theory is beautiful math, but ultimately not physics.

Comment: @ab2, Perhaps I answered too quickly then!  We'll see if the OP heeds your suggestion.

Comment: There are two possible scenarios here ... You try to convince him, but he does not agree with you.  The two possibilities: you present a valid proof (what you think); your alleged proof is not valid (what he thinks).  The word to be used for this guy depends on which of these scenarios you want to assert.

Comment: A *realist*.  You can never have *all* the facts about a topic.

Answer (score 6):

**Skeptical**.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptical

> Relating to, characteristic of, or marked by skepticism.

Example:

> She's highly skeptical of the researchers' claims.

**Skepticism** is defined as:

> An attitude of doubt or a disposition to incredulity either in general or toward a particular object.

In this situation, this is the most apt word.  From the question's description,  it's not at all clear that this person has been presented with irrefutable proof.  He was simply presented with "all the facts".  These is no mention that these facts constitute irrefutable proof.  Thus other words such as **zealous**, **intolerant**, **denier** don't work because they convey the idea that the person is irrational, which cannot be implied based on the question.  **Adamant** and **persistent** don't work because they imply imply some sort of effort, where as it's not the skeptic that is putting in the effort, it is the other party who is presenting the evidence.

Comment: No,  skepticism is the state of demanding supporting evidence.  Once the preponderance of evidence and experiment is consistent with the theory in question, a person who still denies the situation is at best deluded and at worst corrupt (e.g., all climate-change deniers)

Comment: A person may continue to be skeptical if the presented facts, in the opinion of the skeptic, don't constitute a strong-enough case or are flawed.  Please look up the definition of skepticism: "an attitude of doubt or a disposition to incredulity either in general or toward a particular object.".

Comment: In science, the best paper presenting the most ironclad proof still needs to be independently verified before being fully accepted.

Comment: @afeygin You should add that definition to your answer, along with a brief explanation of why you think it applies in this situation. (I think you're right, but that's not obvious with the answer as-is except to people who *already* know the word and its implications). Ping me when you edit and I'll up-vote.

Comment: @afeygin Such a person is no longer a skeptic but a denier, or a person suffering cognitive dissonance.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, the question said that the person is presented with facts.  It doesn't say the person is presented with irrefutable proof.  I may present you with facts that Big Foot exists (a footprint and a blurry photo), but you still may rightly be skeptical.  It doesn't mean that you are a denier--you may still allow for that possibility for Big Foot's existance.  You just find it unlikely.

Comment: @1006a added definition and it's aptness to the question.

Comment: The skeptic may not be convinced that the so-called facts have been assembled in good faith and objectively.

Comment: A major problem with the OP question related to the suitability of the word "skeptic":  The OP condition of "all of the facts" asserts that the absence of unimagined pertinent facts can be proven in the negative. The burden cannot be put on the skeptic to prove the theory wrong else be termed "irrational" or some sort of word indicating being purposefully antagonistic. The more subjective a subject, the more reasonable being a skeptic is. "Did the glove get moved in the OJ case?" If a juror felt so, it becomes more rational to doubt that all existing 'facts' were shared with them objectively.

Answer (score 3):

You might call them [***close-minded***,](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/close-minded) but they would see themselves as being [***faithful***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/faithful) to their consciences.

You might call them overly ***[suspicious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/suspicious)***, but they would see others around them as too quick to believe, ***[gullible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/gullible)*** or even ***[deceived](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/deceive)***.

No matter what you call them, I guarantee the person would see it differently.  No matter how you spin it, they *think* they are being true to the evidence (unless the person is genuinely mentally disabled or they are lying).

What is obvious to you is obviously not obvious to the other.  Calling someone names -- if they are being true to their consciences -- is both mean and bigoted.  Have some respect.  Be patient.  Give them the benefit of the doubt.

You say "all the facts" have been presented, but I guarantee if the other person is not convinced they don't see it that way.

"Fallacies do not cease to be fallacies because they become fashions." - G.K. Chesterton

Answer (score 1):

Here are three words from Merriam Webster that you may find useful

## [Adamant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adamant)

**adjective**

1.
unshakable or insistent especially in maintaining a position or opinion.

Or for a belief (usually religious)

## [Zealous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zealous)

**adjective**
marked by fervent partisanship for a person, a cause, or an ideal

Or if you want to describe someone who could conceivably change their opinion. you could use

## [Persistent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persistent)

existing for a long or longer than usual time or continuously: such as

a :  retained beyond the usual period a persistent leaf

b :  continuing without change in function or structure persistent gills

c :  effective in the open for an appreciable time usually through slow volatilizing mustard gas is persistent

d :  degraded only slowly by the environment persistent pesticides

e :  remaining infective for a relatively long time in a vector after an initial period of incubation persistent viruses

Comment: Please mention your sources by name as well.

Comment: Good. +1 to that.